# Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 and Windows 10. No EFI system partition was found

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, windows

I have two machines, both dual boot with Windows 7 and 10 on separate disks. I believe they are installed BIOS/legacy, not UEFI (Win 10 says "Legacy" for BIOS mode).

I'd like to add Ubuntu, making it triple-boot.

I created an Ubuntu USB image using both Rufus and Universal USB Installer. With Refus I chose "MBR" and "UEFI or Legacy".

However, on both machines I encounter the same two problems during installation:

1. Only report Windows 10 existing. Windows 7 is not mentioned. I assume if I chose this option it might remove Windows 7 from my boot menu.
2. Because of the first problem I chose custom install. After setting root on the Ubuntu partition I get the warning:

`No EFI system partition was found. This system will likely not be able to boot successfully`

I'd like to understand the problems, besides a solution.

**Why isn't Windows 7 being recognised? (is there something I can check and post back here)**

**How can I solve 'no EFI system partition'/install Ubuntu under normal BIOS?**

Comment: Windows 7 is severely past EOL and contains multiple well known vulnerabilities that will never be patched. If you really need it for some reason, put it in a VM without networking.

Comment: @Nmath Could I just disable it's internet connection? And then I can keep all my programs etc? Otherwise I'm losing data.

Comment: I am not sure there is an "ubuntu" or grub answer to this question. Windows 10 and old machines that still run bios is and has always been problematic https://www.itpro.com/operating-systems/microsoft-windows/358036/how-to-reinstall-windows-10-without-losing-data

Comment: You have to boot Ubuntu live installer in BIOS boot mode. If it wants ESP, then that is for UEFI boot. Second Windows install overwrites the Windows boot partition and then adds first install via BCD which Linux cannot see. There are major work arounds by creating two Windows boot partitions and doing repairs, so each has its own boot partition. Then grub can find both installs separately.

Comment: Yes, if you install Windows 7 in a VM like VirtualBox, you can set up the container to have no internet connection